# Fix missing constrains for eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am maintening an eclipse plugin and when I try to launch a configuration I got about 20 `missing constraint` warnings.
e.g.: `org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.lib
Missing Constraint: Import-Package: com.google.commmon.base; version="[14.0.1,19.0.0)"`

`org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.lib_2.8.3`

Where should I check for the existance of the package? Where should it be located? Did I miss something in the configuration? (add required plugins did not solve the problem).

`Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Import-Package` the Java package can be in any plugin which is included in your Target Platform. See the 'Plug-in Development > Target Platform' section of the Preferences for details of the target platform you are using. If you haven't already done so you will need to include a plugin containing this package in the target platform. See [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html) for more details on target platforms.

The `version` says that the plugin containing the plugin containing the package must be at least version 14.0.1 and lower than version 19.0.0.

Comment: I downloaded `emf-mwe`, extracted it and added the location in my target file. The package which is required and is missing is written in the `org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.lib`'s manifest file (which is stored in the `emf-mwe` folder) . Shouldn't the required package be also present in the downloaded archive?

Comment: Not necessarily, many plugin use plugins/packages from other vendors and don't include them in the download.

Comment: Would it be a solution to manually create a repo location and store all the missing jars there then add it to the target?

Comment: A target can have multiple locations so that should work. The locations can just be directories containing plugins, they don't have to be full p2 repositories.

Comment: Yeah, that was my idea to put them in a directory( "a repo") and get them from there. Well, I will validate this as an answer because it somehow fixes my problem, thanks for your help!