# Fixing "Missing Constraint: Import-Package" validation errors for Eclipse plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When trying to run the iTrace plugin as an Eclipse application, I get these plugin validation problems.

[image: validation errors]

I've looked at [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869504/eclipse-oxygen-plug-in-missing-constraint-import-package) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567387/fix-missing-constrains-for-eclipse-plugins), but none of them have answered my question.

I've added both the jna jar and commons-logging to the project's build path, but the validation errors persist.

[image]

I guess the other thing it could be that the Apache ivyDE not working properly, but even then I thought the com.sun.jna issue should be solved by adding the jar to the build path.

EDIT:
Here are the plugins I have for com.sun.jna and org.apache.commons.logging as well as the run configuration.

[image: jna plugins]

[image: org.apache.commons.logging plugins]

[image: run configuration]

EDIT 2: On another machine the plugins validate which is very strange since the installed plugins are very similar.

Here are the corresponding installed plugins for the second machine:

[image: jna plugins for computer 2] 
[image]

I have no idea why these plugins work, but the others don't. They are using slightly different version of Eclipse though.

Comment: Eclipse is looking for those things in plug-ins not jars. Adding to the build path won't solve this. You must find the plug-ins and add them to the workspace or target platform and include them in the Run Configuration.

Comment: @greg-449 Ok, I checked that I have those plugins and the run configuration is launch with "all workspace and enabled target plug-ins". Is that what you meant, or should I check something else too? Thanks

Comment: Are all these plugins actually selected in the Run Configuration? And are the versions correct?

Comment: @greg-449 Well, they aren't manually selected, but I assume since I am launching with all workspace and enabled target plug-ins they should be selected? I added images of the highlighted plugins as well as the current run configuration above. I think the versions match up pretty well assuming I need only one of the versions listed in brackets?

Comment: I updated the post to show the corresponding plugins installed on another machine that doesn't get the validation errors.